# Copy filename of txt file to the first line

Tags: batch-file

As a new user of evernote (on Windows) I find it is impossible to set the title of the imported txt file as the filename. Are there any simple codes which can scan all the txt file in a folder and insert the filename of the txt file (without .txt) together with a new line? (Which means that line 1 of the origin file is moved to line 3). Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a batch code for this task:

```
@echo off
for %%I in (*.txt) do (
    echo %%~nI>"%TEMP%\FileName.tmp"
    echo/>>"%TEMP%\FileName.tmp"
    copy /B "%TEMP%\FileName.tmp" + "%%~I" "%%~I.tmp">nul
    del "%%~I"
    ren "%%~I.tmp" "%%~nxI"
)
del "%TEMP%\FileName.tmp" 2>nul
```

For each file with extension TXT in current working directory the name of the text file without path and file extension is written to a temporary file together with a blank line in directory for temporary files.

Next contents of this temporary file and the current text file are copied together as binary data stream to a new file in current directory with same name as text file, but with .tmp appended as new extension. Parameter `/B` is necessary to avoid that command **copy** appends [^Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) (hexadecimal code value 1A).

Next the original text file is deleted and the .txt.tmp file with file name now inserted in first line and a blank line as second line is renamed back to .txt.

Finally the temporary file is deleted in directory for temporary files.

For more details on the used commands and what `%%~I`, `%%~nI` and `%%~nxI` mean open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands and read all pages of help displayed in the command prompt window for each command.

- `copy /?`
- `del /?`
- `for /?`
- `ren /?`

And read additionally the Microsoft article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `>`, `>>` and `2>nul`.

Comment: Thank you! It does work! One more question: It is possible to reverse this process?

Comment: On Stack Overflow a topic should contain always only 1 question. But yes, it is possible to remove the first 2 lines of text file with a batch file. See Stack Overflow search results for search term [\[batch-file\] remove first lines](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+remove+first+lines).

Comment: Excellent. I used this for html, where I wanted to add the filename as a comment. I replaced this line  
echo %%~nI>"%TEMP%\FileName.tmp"  
by this  
echo ^<!--%%~nI--^>>"%TEMP%\FileName.tmp"